Understanding the Windows 11 "second stage" boot process, i.e.: where to inject a missing driver?
I'm suffering from an unbootable Windows 11 after converting the installation to IRST (Intel® Rapid Storage Technology) / VMD (Intel® Volume Management Device) RAID1 via backup/restore (Using the test version of Acronis True Image). Before I had installed the VMD driver in Windows, but it seems it did not get added to the boot drivers (most likely because it was considered to be not needed at that time).
I found an article (Add and Remove Driver packages to an offline Windows Image) describing how to "inject" a missing driver into a WIM from a WinPE boot medium, and I succeeded to add the missing VMD driver into the recovery WIM.
However I could not find a corresponding WIM for the standard Windows boot (Article Install a boot-start driver describes a re-installation (that is what I want to avoid)).
I had also tried the test version of latest Acronis Universal Restore 2025 (that should be able to fix these kind of problems), but it seems that version has a major bug: Whatever I had tried, it did not succeed (support issue pending).
As I still had some unused space in the RAID, I installed an additional copy of Windows (hoping a new and correct Windows Boot Manager might fix the problem, but it did not).
Now I have a working UEFI boot loader that shows three installations of Windows 11 (two that won't boot, and the newly installed one that lacks a lot of other drivers, but it is able to boot) to select from (I call this (The Windows Boot Manager Partition) the "first" boot stage, because when I select my old Windows, it won't boot (I call this the "second" boot stage, obviously happening before "Windows" can access the drivers actually installed).
So my questions are:

Describe how the second stage of Windows boot loads the drivers needed
If a driver is missing in the step above, can I (and if so: How?) add it so that Windows will boot?


The solution is to disable RST, install the RST drivers, then enable RST

Please read the question: That's what I did, but it did not work.

Your question doesn’t mention you installed the drivers before enabling IRST within the firmware.

Do instructions at https://gist.github.com/TomCan/9644966 for adding a driver by booting from ISO help?

@Ramhound I wrote "Before I had installed the VMD driver in Windows..."; maybe the sentence can be parsed in two different ways, however.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Interesting concept, but how to do it when the machine does not boot?

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Sorry, I feel you did not understand the question at all.

@DrMoishePippik The article sound interesting: I never saw using DISM that way (I only saw variants of first mounting some image, adding or removing drivers, then unmounting and committing the changes). Of course Microsoft wants to hide the details, but I'd be really curious what happens "behind the scenes" when using such commands. I'll try and report...

I wonder who had cast three "close votes" for this question. It's not "user bashing", is it?

Thanks to the comment from DrMoishe Pippik pointing me to GitHub: TomCan/gist:9644966 (Inject drivers in Windows installation after motherboard change) I was able to solve the problem, but still I don't quite understand what happens behind the scenes:
My understanding was that the DISM command can only work on WIM images using the /Image: parameter, but as I could not find such an image in the Windows partition, I did not try this direction.
However it seems that DISM has some built-in magic when specifying /Image:C:\ (you don't have to mount or unmount that "image").
Instead it can "add" the driver rather quickly.
In my case (as said) the drivers were already present in C:\Windows\INF, so the solution was rather simple (I had prepared a WinPE medium with the IRST/VMD drivers, so that the Windows installation can be found on the RAID):

So the commands for the VMD in my case were:

C:>dism /lmage:C:\ /Add-Driver /driver:C:\Windows\INF\iastorav.inf


C:>dism /lmage:C:\ /Add-Driver /driver:C:\Windows\INF\iastorv.inf


(Please don’t screenshot terminal output, instead please copy/paste into a code box.) Normally, specifying only the drive letter won’t work, as the offline image would be Z:\Windows or Z:\Windows\WinSxS, not Z: (C: is usually not the OS partition in WinPE/WinRE). If running Dism on the currently booted OS, /Online is used in lieu of /Image: (IIRC, trying to use /Image: on an online Windows image usually results in an error)

(Cont’d…) It may be the link was simply referenced and the link title doesn’t apply to the current situation, however swapping out a motherboard with different specs than the one Windows was installed on requires generalizing the OS on the original motherboard via SysPrep before booting Windows on the new motherboard (not doing so results in OS instability)

First I agree with the screen shots, so I added the commands used as text; the screen shot (actually taken with my mobile phone) is just to show some more information.. However how to save text in a WinPE environment? Also I don't know what the Z: you are talking about is: In general the C: in WinPW may not be the C: the user might expect, but in my case it was the Windows I wanted to fix (verified with "list volume" in diskpart). It seems you missed that I was running from WinPE. I also don't understand why you are talking about a swapped motherboard. Did you comment the right question?

Z: simply references an arbitrary partition letter since it's unlikely to be used, as the partition letter of the OS partition in WinPE is usually not C: (mentioned in my prior comment). For saving to a text file, copy the terminal output, execute notepad, paste, and save as a text file to any data partition other than X: (it's a RAM drive). I also explained in my prior comment why I talked about a swapped motherboard - please re-read what I wrote.

Well the answer should fit the question; it may be true that a different situation requires a different solution. No motherboard was changed here.
